# One click calling on the Epic 4G?

Tags: calls, phone-app

I've got an Epic 4G (aka Samsung Galaxy S) and one of the things I'm flummoxed by in my transition from my trusty old HTC Dream/G1 is that there are way too many steps to make a phone call.

- Power key to wake the screen;
- Motion to unlock the screen;
- Phone button to pull up the keypad;
- Logs tab to find the last few calls.

Am I the only one trying to use this thing as a phone? Am I the only person who mostly calls the same three people all the time?

Is there a faster way to get to my call log? On the G1 I could press the phone button, unlock and I was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution ... I got a new phone.

Answer (score 3):

After unlocking, when I press the Phone icon (on the TouchWiz interface's dock at the bottom of the home screen) it takes me to the last dialler view I used, whether that's the keypad, Log or Favourites. Doesn't yours do that?

If you literally mean the same 3 people, then the quickest way would to put a shortcut for them on your home screen. Just long-press on an empty bit of homescreen background, select Shortcuts, select Direct Dial, select your person.

Alternatively, Star the contacts in GMail, then put a Starred Contacts folder on the homescreen (long-press on an empty bit of homescreen background, select Folders, select Starred Contacts).

*PS yes you probably are one of the few using it as a phone, these are smart phones for people who love email/messaging and internet apps, not dumb-phones for making calls on ;-)*

Comment: I prefer to think of mine as a "mini super computer with phone attachment" given how rarely people seem to use them as actual phones.

Comment: *you* tell that to my father. "She'd love to call you to chat, but that's not how phones work anymore, old man."

Comment: Anyway, it isn't really the same three people, but it tends to be "Now I have an answer for M and I can call her back."

Comment: @Amanda have you tried either of these apps that claim to give you a shortcut straight to your recent calls list? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nexmon.CallLogShortcut https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyphasignals.calllog

Comment: I forgot to mention that I refuse to log in to Google, so I have to be able to get the app outside the market! I've got Dialer One, which is a slight improvement: https://code.google.com/p/dialerone/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't count unlocking the phone against the steps needed to make a phone call.  It's an equivalent of opening up a flip-phone, for example.  You can also disable the lock screen altogether if you're willing to trade the security for a little convenience.

In terms of making it easier to dial contacts, you can always add a "Contact" or "Direct dial" shortcut to your home screen (`Menu -> Add -> Shortcuts -> Contact` or `Direct dial`).  This way after unlocking the phone you have a one-tap-dial for your most used contacts.  Also, most manufacturer overlays (like Touchwiz, Sense or MotoBLUR) come with various contacts-related widgets that you can place on the home screen for faster access to contacts.  Not to mention a plethora of 3rd-party Launchers, apps and widgets from the Market that provide a similar functionality.

*[Edit]*
CyanogenMod ROM allows you to add another configurable "unlock" slider to the lockscreen which you can assign any application, including the Call Log. This way unlocking using that slider places you into whichever app you specified. For stock ROMs you can try the [Widgetlocker Lockscreen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) app to give you similar functionality.

Comment: If I had a flip phone, I'd be able to long press the call button and call. It'd be even easier.

Comment: I did my fair share of butt-dialing on my old Nokia dumbphone before I learned to lock the darn thing.  CyanogenMod custom ROM allows you to add another configurable "unlock" slider to the lockscreen which you can assign any application, including the Call Log.  This way unlocking using that slider places you into whichever app you specified.  For stock ROMs you can try "Widgetlocker Lockscreen" app to give you a similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Hi maybe this app can help you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mafko.instantcall&hl=en

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Martin! Just throwing a link without explanation is not considered an answer here. Could you please [edit] your post and include *how* this app can be of help? What does it do? Also note OP wants a faster way to access the ***call logs*** – not to make an "instant phone call".